# How to delete only one json object using Vue.axios.delete()

Tags: json, vuejs2, axios, json-server

The problem is when I delete one user from fakeserver localhost:3000/users, other users are getting deleted as well.

I tried

```
Vue.axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/' + this.idToDelete )
```

and

```
Vue.axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users', {params: {id:  this.idToDelete} })
```

Some of my html code

```
<v-text-field v-model="idToDelete" type="number" hide-details outline label="Enter Id to delete"></v-text-field>
<v-btn @click="userIdtoDelete()" color="error">Delete</v-btn>
```

Some of my javascript code

```
data () {
    return {
        idToDelete: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    userIdtoDelete () {
        Vue.axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/' + this.idToDelete)


    }
}
```

I have the rest of the code in https://github.com/boidurja/users.git

And the fakeserver is in https://github.com/boidurja/fakeserver.git

I expect that when I click the delete button only one user should get deleted. But actually more than one users are getting deleted. Can anyone find the problem? I would be grateful.

Comment: Could you check in your browser network's panel what is the actual request's url?

Comment: when I use this approach                         
             axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/', {params: {id:  this.idToDelete} })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error)
                alert('error = ' + error)
            }) I get error Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: @alx.lzt Did you mean this url? - localhost:3000/users/3